# How many ships can dock at DS9 at the same time?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

How many ships can be docked at Deep Space 9 at the same time?

Does the number of ships depend on their size?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> 6 large docking pylon ports; 3 medium docking ring ports; 9 small docking ring ports; 6 landing pads - https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Deep_Space_9

[image]

**It can presumably accommodate 6 large vessels at one time. Although I can't think of a time when we've seen all 6 being used. 6 + 3 + 9 + 6 = at least 24 ships (depending on size).**

[image]

Three Galaxy class starships on the upper pylons might be pretty tight, but look they they could all fit.

[image]

The Defiant was often parked on one of the small or medium docking ports.

[image]

Additionally there are launch pads and internal docking bays for smaller vessels, such as the runabouts.

[image]

*Note: Pylon images taken from Memory-Alpha

Comment: Why were the docking pylons necessary? Couldn't ships park a safe distance from DS9 and then transport (beam) crewmembers to the station?

Comment: @RobertF Sure, but every time transporter technology is used there's a small risk of separating the tranportee's yin and yang or creating a clone that later turns evil or even entering a parallel universe.  I'd rather just walk through a door if possible.

Comment: @RobertF What if the transporters are down or disabled? What if the ship is damaged and can't maintain orbit around the station? What if the ship's shield's are damaged and they want to stay close to DS9? What if the entire crew of the ship needs (or wants) to board DS9? What if there are maintenance crews coming in and out that don't want to tie up the transporter? What if... the point is that there are plenty of reasons a ship would dock.

Comment: Note that even Federation-created Starbases usually have ships docking (internally).

Comment: Yes good points. But the DS9 docking pylons look awfully fragile, don't they?

Comment: It should be noted that the size of DS9 was subject to vary (the station was scaled up especially when very large ships such as Galaxy class vessels were docked). With this in mind, it is somewhat questionable whether more than two ships can be docked at the pylon at a time (one at the upper pylons, one at the lower ones). Navigating amidst the inward-facing pylons already seems unnecessarily risky for only one ship (consider the possible damage in case of a collision), and having two or three ships maneuver in that small area would further mulitply that risk.

Comment: It's not so much that the scale varied, as it was never consistently scaled in the first place. The interior and exterior designs assume at least a 2x difference IIRC, in addition to inconsistent sizes for the various ship types that dock there (size of *Defiant* relative to *Galaxy* class varies quite a lot in itself).

Comment: Your image is slightly incorrect about the placement of the landing pads. The landing pads for small ships like runabouts were placed around the "top" of the habitat ring, as circled [here](http://i.imgur.com/Rms9OfO.jpg) and more obviously seen [here](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/articles/ferengi-shuttle/runabout-ds9-bay.jpg) and [here](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/articles/ferengi-shuttle/shuttle-themagnificentferengi3.jpg)

Comment: Wasn't the station designed by Cardassians? That means the pylons were  designed for Cardassian ships, so though Federation ships would be tight, perhaps Cardassian ones fit nicely.

Comment: 6 + 3 + 9 + 6 = **24**, not 25.

Comment: @wikis math is hard.

Comment: @Leushenko: "It's not so much that the scale varied, as it was never consistently scaled in the first place." - if it's not consistently scaled, isn't that exactly the same as saying the scale varied? The [size of the Defiant is indeed subject to debate](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/articles/defiant-problems.htm), however both the sizes of the Galaxy class and of Danube class runabouts are fairly certain. It would be interesting to find out whether the scale of the station matches when seen together with these ships.

Comment: According to [Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Space_9#Station_layout) (which in my experience is a reasonably reliable source), the diameter of the station was variously described as anywhere from ~3360 ft (1024 m) to ~5280 ft (1609 m, 1 mi).  The Technical Manual compromised with a value between those extremes.  But all of those numbers are quite large, by any measure.  For reference, a *Galaxy*-class starship is [2108 ft or 642.5 m](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Space_9#Station_layout) from bow to stern.

Answer (score 4):

Deep Space 9 had 6 [docking pylons](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Docking_pylon): 3 on the top and 3 on the bottom (referred to as "upper pylons" and "lower pylons").

> The docking pylons were a series of six large structures attached to Deep Space 9's docking ring. These sweeping modules contained the large ore processing facilities, and also permitted the docking of large starships at the station. The pylons were generally referred to by their position relative to the station's horizontal axis and a designated number, for example "Upper pylon 1" or "Lower pylon 3". At the end of the pylons were docking bays, where large starships could dock with the station.

Additionally, Deep Space 9 had 6 more [internal docking bays](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Docking_bay):

> Not all docking bays were located within a structure. Deep Space 9 had a total of twelve docking bays of which six were external, called docking pylons. They were used to facilitate large ships which did not fit into the internal docking bays.

So the answer is **6 large ships** and **at least 6 small ships**. More than one small ship can fit into an internal docking bay, so the number really depends on how small the ships are.

These are pretty much the first results for googling "Deep Space 9 docks", so I'm surprised your research didn't tell you all of this already.

Comment: @amaretto I'm not complaining, just pointing out a resource. Teach a man to fish, and all that.

Comment: @Kevin Workman Keep in mind that Google results depend on your past search history and the search history for your Internet "neighbors" as well.  Something that can come up as a first search result for you, might not be the first (or even first few pages) search result for someone else. This can be especially frustrating if you're just starting to move into a field with no previous search history in it.

Comment: @AndrejaKo Again, I'm not complaining. But I'm pretty sure the Memory Alpha page on Deep Space 9, which both answers are basic copies of, would show up in most reasonable google searches for this question. Posting trivia questions for the sake of rep farming is fine, but if we're actually trying to help people learn, then helping them realize that google can answer many questions like this is the best way to help them. Different strokes for different folks, I suppose.

Comment: Also I have often "Googled" something, ended up here or a forum site and the answer has been "Google It"

Comment: @user001 Again. My answer includes links to the answer, as well as the answer itself. I just also pointed out that google is good at this kind of question. Some people are here to just answer trivia, but I like to think this site is also for actually educating people. Politely pointing out that google is an option is the best way to help people who really want to know trivial answers.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Your answer may do, but may here do not and I have been directed to Stack Exchange before and had nothing but "Google is your friend" as the only "answer"

Comment: @user001 I understand that, but that's not at all what I did, so I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do with the information. If you're frustrated with other answers, maybe comment on them?

Comment: @KevinWorkman What I am saying is that they may have tried to do research and just kept getting told to "Google it", hence their own research not showing an answer

Comment: @user001 For the fifth time: **that's not what I did**. I gave the user an answer, as well as a link to where they could find the answer. Then I simply mentioned that I'm surprised this didn't show up on Google. Can you show me where I told the person to "just google it"? Notice that if the user already did some googling, **they should have mentioned that in the original post**, and the mouseover for the downvote button says **this question does not show any research effort**.